# Prime number finder

Tags: python, primes

So I am trying to make a prime number finder, and to save computation time I want it to abort the forloop once it finds a divisor which is not 1 or the number itself. Now the function works, but it completely ignores my ifstatement. What am I doing wrong?

```
def prime(number):
    oldnum = number
    factor = 1
    while number > 1:
        factor += 1
        while number % factor == 0:
            if 1< factor < oldnum:
                return 0 # is not prime
                print("yay")
                break
            number //= factor
    return 1 #prime!
```

Comment: it only breaks the second while loop?

Comment: @HagbartCeline: It would, if it was ever reached :)

Comment: What makes you believe it ignores your `if`? If that were ignored, `prime` could never return anything but 1. But it returns 0 for composite arguments.

Comment: Well, it never prints yay. Which is a solid indication :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code never reaches the line `return 1` (which should be `return True`, by the way) because

- your `break` statement would only break out of the inner `while` loop
- that `break` statement isn't ever reached because you `return 0` before that.

Your inner `while` loop should be an `if`, anyway (since you're not actually doing anything that requires looping).

If you change that (and remove the unreachable code), it "works" (besides the erronenous result of `prime(1)` being `True`), it's a very inefficient way of finding prime numbers.

```python
def prime(number):
    oldnum = number
    factor = 1
    while number > 1:
        factor += 1
        if number % factor == 0:
            if 1 < factor < oldnum:
                return False # is not prime
            number //= factor
    return True # is prime!
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a little comment on the improvement of performance, you need to check only the factors `from 2 to sqrt(num)`, instead of `2 to num`.

Comment: I think Math.ceiling(sqrt(num)) will be better...since num may not always be a perfect square.

Comment: @Sreekanth If sqrt(num) is not an integer then it is sufficient to check up to math.floor(sqrt(num)).

Answer (score 3):

Just use [Erathostenes's sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It's an old and proven method to find primes :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this function ?

`import math

def prime(number):
  if number == 1:
    return 1
  for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1):
    if number % i == 0:
      return 0
  return 1`

Comment: What if *number* == 49? Plus syntax error in *range* (comma), plus invalid type (expect integer) ....

Comment: arf thanks for the comments, my python is a bit rusty... I will edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your ultimate objective is to find primes effectively, and others have answered the coding problem very well, I'll go into a bit more detail than other answers on how to do it more efficiently.

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is the fastest way of *finding* primes up to 10 million or so. But you seem to want to determine if just some given number `n` is prime or not.

To check if a number `n` is prime you only need to check if it is divisible by *primes* which are *less than or equal* to `sqrt(n)`. So using this method, if you want your function to handle numbers up to 100 million, you'll only need to prepare a list of all the primes up to 10000 (1229 primes), which will take a negligible amount of time.

If you're interested I can put in my sieve implementation here, but I'm guessing you're solving this problem for your own amusement, so I'll leave you to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim points out you need the inner while to be an if. Something like this will work (but be horribly inefficient)

```
def prime(number):
    oldnum = sqrt(number)
    factor = 1
    while factor <= oldnum:
        factor += 1
        if number % factor == 0 :
            return 0 # is not prime
    return 1 #prime!
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree to above answers..
A number x is said to be prime if it has only factors 1 and itself ...
The ideal method will be to check whether there are any factors from 2 to ceiling function(sqrt(x))...
where the ceiling function (n) refers to smallest integer greater than or equal to n.

The function in C would look like...

// function returns..
 {
   -> -1 for neither prime nor composite..
   ->  0 for composite numbers..
   ->  1 for prime numbers..
  }

.....................................

```
 boolean isPrime(int n){

     if(n<=1){
       return -1;
     }else{
      for(int i=2;i<Math.sqrt(n);i++){
        if(n%i==0)
         return 1;
      }
      return 0;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (implementation of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)).

```
def squares_till(n):
    def square_add(i,n):
        j = i**2
        while j < n:
            yield j
            j = j + i
    A = [True]*n
    A[0] = A[1] = False
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)):
        if A[i]:
            for j in square_add(i,n):
                A[j] = False
    return [num for num in range(n) if A[num]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, this is very efficient implementation. It may be further improved by incorporation Primality test (O(1) implementation).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printN(const vector<int> container, int count, ostream& out=cout, const string& delim=", ") {
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        out << container[i] << delim;
    out << endl;
}

void printNPrimes(int count) {
    static const int FIRST_PRIME = 2;
    static vector<int> primes(1, FIRST_PRIME);
    static int rangeEnd = 3;

    if(primes.size() >= count) {
        printN(primes, count);
        return;
    }

    int remainingPrimeNumbers = count - primes.size();

    while(remainingPrimeNumbers) {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for(int prime : primes) {
            if(rangeEnd % prime == 0) {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(is_prime) {
            primes.push_back(rangeEnd);
            --remainingPrimeNumbers;
        }

        ++rangeEnd;
    }

    printN(primes, count);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        cout << "usage: rund <count>";
        return -1;
    }

    int count = atoi(argv[1]);
    printNPrimes(count);
    return 0;
}
```